# composition generalized to K-convexity

Tags: convex-optimization

I am self-studying [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) by Boyd and Vandenberghe. I am currently at page 111 where the author states:

> If $g : R^n → R^p$ is *K*-convex, $h : R^p → R$ is convex, and $\tilde{h}$ (the extended-value extension of *h*) is *K*-nondecreasing, then $ h \circ g$ is convex. This generalizes the fact that a nondecreasing convex function of a convex function is convex. **The condition that $\tilde{h}$ be K-nondecreasing implies that **dom** *h* − *K* = **dom** *h*.**

I don't really get the last part. Can someone explain why **dom** *h* and *K* must be disjoint?

If I think of a really straightforward example:

$g(x_1,...,x_{n-1},x_n) = [x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$, where ${\bf dom }\:{\it g} = R^{n}$ and

$h(x_1,...,x_{n-2},x_{n-1}) = x_1$, where ${\bf dom }\:{\it h} = R^{n-1}$.

Let the cone be $K = R^{n-1}_{+}$, the $n-1$ dimensional nonnegathive orthant. Then *g* is *K*-convex, *h* is convex and *K*-nondeacreasing, so $ h \circ g$ is convex, but ${\bf dom }\:{\it h} − {\it K} \neq {\bf dom }\:{h}$.